# Filter books according to the book types and advanced types (React.js, MongoDB, Express)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I am creating a full-stack comic book system, in the main page, it will show all the books in the database, there is an input box for the user to search the book name, and there are category buttons for the user to filter the books by the book types. I had made the rendering of all books and search for book name features work, but I cannot filter the books by categories, it just did nothing. I am just doing the filter category feature on the frontend but not the backend, which I watched some Youtube tutorials, they are all doing it on the frontend-side only. Please have a look at my codes, what I have done wrong.

Database model

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bookName: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: String
    },
    publisher: {
        type: String
    },
    yearReleased: {
        type: Number
    },
    type: {
        type: String
    },
    advancedBookType: {
        type: String
    },
    bookDescription: {
        type: String
    },
    rentalPrice: {
        type: Number
    },
    bookStatus: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Available', 'Pending to pickup', 'Lent out', 'Overdue'],
        default: "Available"
    },
    bookImage: {
        type: String
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
```

I am just using string as datatype of the book type, but not an enum, would that be a problem?

React main page component

```
class BookTableUser extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            books: [],
            searchText: '',
            typeButton: ''
        }

        this.changeSearchText = this.changeSearchText.bind(this);
        this.filterItem = this.filterItem.bind(this);
    }

filterItem = (typeButton) => {
        this.updatedItems = this.state.books.filter((book) => {
            return book.type === typeButton;
        });

        this.setState(this.updatedItems);
    }

render() {
        const { typeButton } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='layout-container'>
                <div className='sidebar'>
                    <input className='searchbar' type="text" placeholder='Search book....' onChange={this.changeSearchText} value={this.state.searchText} />

                    <div className='all-types-container'>
                        <div className='all-container'>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.setState(this.state.books)}>All</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='types-container'>
                            <h5>Book type</h5>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Comedy')}>Comedy</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Love')}>Love</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Horror')}>Horror</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Detecting')}>Detecting</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Fiction')}>Fiction</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Adventure')}>Adventure</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Action')}>Action</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Youth')}>Youth</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='advanced-types-container'>
                            <h5>Advanced book type</h5>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('Popular')}>Popular</button>
                            <button className='type-button' onClick={() => this.filterItem('New release')}>New release</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="card-group">
                    <div className="container">
                        if (!typeButton) {
                            <div className="row row-cols-3">

                                {this.state.books.filter((book) => {
                                    return book.bookName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchText.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                                }).map(book => (
                                    <div className="card" style={{ height: 500 + 'px', width: 300 + 'px' }} key={book._id}>
                                        <img src={`http://localhost:3001/${book.bookImage}`} className="card-img-top" alt="comic book coverpage" />
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                            <Link to={`/books/${book._id}`}><h5 className="card-title">{book.bookName}</h5></Link>
                                            <p className="card-text">{book.bookDescription}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>))}
                            </div>
                        } else {
                            <div>
                                {this.state.books.filter(book => {
                                    return book.type == typeButton;
                                })}
                            </div>
                        }
```

Comment: The way you are updating state inside filterItem is not correct. There are three properties in state object. You have to update only the one that you intend to change.

Comment: @B.Anup The three properties in the state object are for different purposes. The books in an empty array is for fetching all the books in the database, the searchText in an empty string is for searching the book name which matches the typed in text in an input box. I had successfully made these two functionalities working, so I didn't include the codes in this snippet.This snippet here is for finding what I had done wrong in clicking the button to filter out the book according to the type button the user clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the way state has been updated. State have three properties, you have to modify properties that you are intended to do, remaining properties should be kept untouched.

```
filterItem = (typeButton) => {
        let updatedItems = this.state.books.filter((book) => {
            return book.type === typeButton;
        });
        this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {
            ...prevState,
            ['books']: updatedItems
        })
        this.setState(this.updatedItems);
    }
```

You can improve the design of this component. If this doesn't solve your problem, Could you please create a sandbox for the same(only frontend).

Comment: I followed a Youtube tutorial to write this piece of code, it works perfectly in the Youtube video, but the Youtuber is using a functional component in her codes, I am using a class component, I tried to modify her codes to suit my situation, but it doesn't work for me. The Youtube link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPH7sCyXFb4

Comment: Could you create a sandbox of your project?

Comment: Here is my codes sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/mvou32